# Total records processed in each micro batch spark streaming

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Is there a way I can find how many records got processed into downstream delta table for each micro-batch. I've streaming job, which runs hourly once using **trigger.once()** with the **append mode**. For audit purpose, I want to know how many records got processed for each micro batch. I've tried the below code to print the count of records processed(shown in the second line).

```
ss_count=0 

def write_to_managed_table(micro_batch_df, batchId):
#print(f"inside foreachBatch for batch_id:{batchId}, rows in passed dataframe: {micro_batch_df.count()}")

ss_count = micro_batch_df.count()

saveloc = "TABLE_PATH"
df_final.writeStream.trigger(once=True).foreachBatch(write_to_managed_table).option('checkpointLocation', f"{saveloc}/_checkpoint").start(saveloc)

print(ss_count)
```

Streaming job will run without any issues but **micro_batch_df.count()** will not print any count.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the print statement getting printed without count value or entire print statement is missing?

Comment: Entire print statement is missing @FelixKJose

Comment: did you try the println outside of the function "write_to_managed_table"? I believe when its inside a function it will be printed on the worker instead of the driver node.

Comment: @puligun, edited the above code accordingly to get the count outside the function, post micro batch processing output of ss_count shows as 0.

Comment: try not using the function at all. just do println(dataframe.count)

Comment: @chaitrak Please let me know if the following answer helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of what you are looking for **(structured_steaming_example.py):**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("StructuredStreamTesting") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create DataFrame representing the stream of input
df = spark.read.parquet("data/")
lines = spark.readStream.schema(df.schema).parquet("data/")


def batch_write(output_df, batch_id):
    print("inside foreachBatch for batch_id:{0}, rows in passed dataframe: {1}".format(batch_id, output_df.count()))


save_loc = "/tmp/example"
query = (lines.writeStream.trigger(once=True)
         .foreachBatch(batch_write)
         .option('checkpointLocation', save_loc + "/_checkpoint")
         .start(save_loc)
         )
query.awaitTermination()
```

The sample parquet file is attached. Please put that in the data folder and execute the code using spark-submit

```
spark-submit --master local structured_steaming_example.py
```

**Please put any sample parquet file under data folder for testing.**

[image]